# sortedArrayUsingComparators not sorting numbers in ascending order

Tags: ios, sorting, nsstring, nsmutablearray

So this is probably really simple but I'm running into a problem with the sortedArrayUsingComparators method. I'm trying to sort an array of NSStrings that only contain number. For example, I have an array of strings: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,8,9,11,12. When I run it using my code, I don't get a sorted result. In fact, I don't think the array changes order. Could someone help me out what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's the code snippet:

```
[tmp sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {

    NSInteger first = obj1.integerValue;
    NSInteger second = obj2.integerValue;

    if (first < second)
    {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
}];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `tmp` will not change, a new sorted array is returned.

Assuming `tmp` is an `NSArray` then try

```
tmp = [tmp sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {

    NSInteger first = obj1.integerValue;
    NSInteger second = obj2.integerValue;

    if (first < second)
    {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
}];
```

If `tmp` is an `NSMutableArray` then try `-sortUsingComparator:` instead of `-sortedArrayUsingComparator:`

```
[tmp sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {

    NSInteger first = obj1.integerValue;
    NSInteger second = obj2.integerValue;

    if (first < second)
    {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks! I was careless with that.